# In R: git2r_remote_ls': Failed to retrieve list of SSH authentication methods

Tags: r, ssh, gitlab, devtools, libgit2

I have an issue on installing packages from this private [gitlab account](https://gitlab.com/aprl/AIRSpec/-/tree/master/). I generated public and private keys through PuTTYgen and used it to communicate with above website. Here is the piece of code I used from the website:

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("git2r")

library(devtools)
library(git2r)

creds <- git2r::cred_ssh_key("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "~/.ssh/id_rsa")

pkglist <- c("AIRSpec", "Rfunctools", "APRLspec", "APRLmpf", "APRLmvr", "APRLssb")

for(pkg in pkglist) {
  print(paste("Installing package:", pkg, "..."))

  ## install package
  devtools::install_git(sprintf("git@gitlab.com:aprl/%s.git", pkg), 
                     credentials = creds)

  ## install dependencies
  descr <- readLines(file.path(.libPaths(), pkg, "DESCRIPTION"))
  deps <- strsplit(sub("^Imports: ", "", grep("^Imports: ", descr, 
                value=TRUE)), ", ")
  if (exist("deps$1"))  install.packages(deps[[1]])
}
```

However, I get this error message:

`"Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Git: Error in 'git2r_remote_ls': Failed to retrieve list of SSH authentication methods: Failed getting response"`

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Nourolah

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found this [github issue](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/1013#issuecomment-679200156), that issue is filled for the python bindings of `libgit2`. They propose to generate the ssh keys in the PEM format via:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the permissions of the `.ssh` files. Fixing the files permissions solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out your target server keys format will accept

   ```
   ssh -o "HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa" 11.11.11.11 -p 22
   ```

   Output will tell you what key types you need:

   ```
   Unable to negotiate with 11.11.11.11 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
   ```
2. Create a key with type that it accepts

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519
   ```